# Instantiation of objects in compiled GWT code

Tags: javascript, gwt, compiler-optimization

I notice in browsing my compiled GWT code that there are many, many calls to empty $$init_nn functions such as below where $$init_1005 has an empty function body.  Was there originally some code in $$init_1005 that got optimized out?  Does it serve any purpose now?  Can the empty functions and the calls to them be eliminated?

Thanks

```
function $$init_1005() {
}
...

function TreeSet_0(c){
  AbstractSet_0.call(this);
  $$init_1005();   // <-- Call to empty function
  isNull(c)?(this.map = new TreeMap_0):(this.map = new TreeMap_1(c));
}
```

Comment: Could it be a stub that is meant to be replaced with another function later?  Like a placeholder in a dynamically linked library?

Comment: When compiling in PRETTY, make sure to turn the optimizations all the way up - by default, the compiler lowers the optimization level in PRETTY style.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, GWT using $$init_ function to initialize object fields, when they are initialized directly at declaration 
E.g. for:

```
public class Test {
 final String value = "1";
 final String value2= "2";
}
```

GWT will create a function like this:

```
function $$init_55(this$static) {
 this$static.value = "1";
 this$static.value2 = "2";
}
```

Usually it is always in-lined or removed if it is empty, but if you turn off optimization (e.g. flags -optimize 0 or -draftCompile) it will stay there.

One of other possible reasons might be  that GWT is not optimizing all of your code the same way. As far as I remember it is trying to optimize some parts as hard as possible and for others it does only some basic optimization.

Comment: When setting style to PRETTY, optimizations are mostly turned off, which helps readability, unless the bug you are after is optimization based...

Comment: Just tried on my GWT project ( GWT 2.4.0), can't find a single $$init in compiled JS, unless I use flags -draftCompile or -optimize 0. It is true that some optimizations are turned off in PRETTY mode, but usually dead code removal and in-lining works in PRETTY mode same as in OBFUSCATED mode. At least when I've found some bugs with this optimizations, I've found them in both PRETTY and OBFUSCATED mode.